# Centos 7 FirewallD failing to start from fresh OVH install

Tags: iptables, firewall, centos7

I've just received a new 32GB dedicated server from OVH and installed Centos7 just like my other VPS.

Only the issue now is when I start FirewallD on the OVH dedicated server it complains with an issue to do with iptables-restore?

I'm not entirely sure why my dedicated servers install was different to my VPS but all the ports were public by default so I suspect there's something OVH has done to the image to open all ports from the start.

I can see its complaining about line 11 and 10, but I don't understand what the error means.

Message running systemctl status firewalld:

```
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-12-02 00:25:34 CET; 8s ago
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
 Main PID: 16147 (firewalld)
   CGroup: /system.slice/firewalld.service
           └─16147 /usr/bin/python2 -Es /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid

Dec 02 00:25:34 dedi systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
Dec 02 00:25:34 dedi systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.

Dec 02 00:25:34 dedi firewalld[16147]: ERROR: '/usr/sbin/iptables-restore -w -n' failed: iptables-restore v1.4.21: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'security'

                                               Error occurred at line: 11...
    Dec 02 00:25:34 dedi firewalld[16147]: ERROR: '/usr/sbin/ip6tables-restore -w -n' failed: ip6tables-restore v1.4.21: ip6tables-restore: unable to initialize table 'security'

                                               Error occurred at line: 11...
    Dec 02 00:25:34 dedi firewalld[16147]: ERROR: '/usr/sbin/iptables-restore -w -n' failed: iptables-restore v1.4.21: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'security'

                                               Error occurred at line: 10...
    Dec 02 00:25:34 dedi firewalld[16147]: ERROR: '/usr/sbin/ip6tables-restore -w -n' failed: ip6tables-restore v1.4.21: ip6tables-restore: unable to initialize table 'security'

                                               Error occurred at line: 10...
    Dec 02 00:25:34 dedi firewalld[16147]: ERROR: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/ip6tables-restore -w -n' failed: ip6tables-restore v1.4.21: ip6tables-restore: unable to initialize table 'security'

                                               Error occurred at line: 10...
```

Answer (score -1):

I just got the same OVH server and found the same problem.
I used a workaround and did not search the root cause pf not loading security table.
https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/issues/484#issuecomment-484109353